# Query/Find Oracle Queries that populate an Applications Data

Tags: sql, oracle, forms

I work with an application that uses an Oracle Database to administer its data. Within the application we have a form that searches data from the database and surfaces up the results. Often times, I use the results from the search dialogue to confirm the the SQL queries I build to ensure I am getting correct results.

I got to thinking that there must be SQL's being run the in the background that queries the database when someone uses the search form. If I am correct, how would I go about finding those queries? Is there a logical place I can find them? (I use SQL Developer mostly to access the database). Are they even stored in the database? Stored in the application? Stored somewhere else? Would this be dependent upon how the application was designed?

This is a case of 'I don't know what I don't know'.

I have reached out to the manager of the application and this person kinda shrugged their shoulders and didn't know either. We do have a contractor that manages the database but because we bill them every time we ask them for something, I have been told not to ask for this. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Oracle is designed to allow SQL queries run concurrently. Why do you think "SQL's being run the in the background that queries the database when someone uses the search form" is causing problem? And what's the actual problem? Can you log the SQL queries you build somewhere to ensure you are running the query you want?

Comment: @Fat P There is no problem. I am just looking for the application or database queries that are run in my stack so that I can leverage them and build upon them on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

You should, probably, try to find the particular SQLs info somewhere within (quite a few) Oracle's **v$** views. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-2B9DD73A-4C3A-467A-A934-01B705AB77A8.htm#REFRN-GUID-2B9DD73A-4C3A-467A-A934-01B705AB77A8
Maybe one of these two SQLs could help you to find what you are looking for:

1. v$SQLAREA

```sql
Select * 
From v$SQLAREA
Where SubStr(nvl(ACTION, 'SYS'), 1, 3) != 'SYS'
```

2. v$SESSION, v$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY, v$SQLAREA, DBA_OBJECTS

```sql
Select
    ses.SID "SID",
    ses.SERIAL# "SERIAL_NO",
    sql.SQL_FULLTEXT "SQL_FULLTEXT",
    obj.OBJECT_NAME "OBJ_NAME",
    obj.owner "OBJ_OWNER",
    ash.event "EVENT",
    ash.session_state "SESSION_STATE",
    ash.top_level_sql_id "TOP_LEVEL_SQL_ID",
    ash.sql_exec_id "SQL_EXEC_ID",
    to_char(ash.sql_exec_start, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "SQL_EXEC_START",
    ash.*
From
    v$SESSION ses
Inner Join
    v$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY ash on ses.SID = ash.SESSION_ID and ses.SERIAL# = ash.SESSION_SERIAL#  
Left Join
    v$SQLAREA sql on ash.TOP_LEVEL_SQL_ID = sql.SQL_ID                              
Left Join
    DBA_OBJECTS obj on ash.CURRENT_OBJ# = obj.OBJECT_ID
Where
    ash.SQL_EXEC_ID Is Not Null
Order By
    ash.SAMPLE_ID desc
```

Regards...